# How can I make a node js addon for C++?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, electron, node-modules

I am trying to create a windows desktop application using C++ as backend and javascript for the fornt-end. I created a database in MySQL and successfully connected it to C++. I installed node js version 18.17.1 LTS, installed the package, installed electron, and installed node js API (for the addon). I made all the necessary linking for the header files. I created a file called addon.cpp and here's the code for it:

```
#include <napi.h>

Napi::String Method(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
Napi::Env env = info.Env();
return Napi::String::New(env, "Hello from C++ backend!");
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
exports.Set("sayHello", Napi::Function::New(env, Method));
return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

Visual Studio 2022 is giving me an error on this line of code 'NODE_API_MODULE(addon, Init)' telling me that identifier napi_value is undefined

Note: I am still a beginner so please bare with me.

Obviously I asked help from ChatGPT, but nothing helped, I tried to downgrade to node js version 14.7.0, tried re installing everything from scratch, still the same error kept on going. I've came too far setting up my project in order to start. I don't want to go back or change the programming language. I am really comfortable with C++ and all the GUI made for C++ are complicated (such as Qt), I find myself learning javascript way smoother. So please if someone can help me with this addon so i could start my project and call functions from my C++ files, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Building nodejs addons requires proper setup of your build settings, which is why the documentation recommends to use one of two tools to do it for you: https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html#build-tools

Comment: Why do you use C++ to work with MySQL but not node/electron modules and/or ORM like sequelize.js? This will avoid using not trivial for newbies integration native code to node,js.

Comment: Try looking at [C++ addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).